# Android: Choosing the right settings to prepare ActivityResultLauncher for picking contacts

Tags: java, android, uri

After 4 hours of trying and reading the documentation I cannot resolve problems getting Uri data  when using ActivityResultLauncher in place of my working but deprecated solution of picking contacts and contentResolver to use the data.

The copied code at least enables me to successfully pick a contact using the launched intent, but applying [...data.setData((Uri) uriData)...] results in a NULL pointer exception for getContentResolver.

I have tried declaring ActivityResultLauncher as a String and as Uri with ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()  but when I think I am close, I cannot find the right parameters to launch the ContactContracts.... PickContact as it has no MIME, but with using intent, I cannot get a Uri result.  Guess that's why they only document the easy solutions on the Developer site, such as picking an image MIME.

```
Public class InvoiceFragment extends Fragment implements InvoiceListAdapter.OnInvoiceItemListener{
private InvoiceListAdapter iAdapter;
private SubTotalListAdapter sAdapter;
private Locale locale = new Locale("en", "UK");
private NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
Float invoiceTotal;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager invLayoutManager;
DatabaseHelper myDb;
final Uri uriData = null;
//ArrayList<InvoiceItem> invoiceItemList = new ArrayList<>();
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {


            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                Intent data = result.getData();
                data.setData((Uri) uriData);

                Cursor c =  getContext().getContentResolver().query(uriData, null, null, null, null);
                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + name);
                    c.close();

                }
            }




        });
```

Then Launching it!

```
       view.findViewById(R.id.btGetContact).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (checkPermissions(getActivity(), READ_CONTACTS)) {
                Intent contactsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                //contactsIntent.setData((Uri) uriData);

                mStartForResult.launch(contactsIntent);
            }


        }
    });
```

Results in

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {wytonmcs.com.accounts/wytonmcs.com.accounts.InvoiceActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3581)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1638)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
    at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:128)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:737)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:704)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:662)
    at wytonmcs.com.accounts.InvoiceFragment$1.onActivityResult(InvoiceFragment.java:70)
    at wytonmcs.com.accounts.InvoiceFragment$1.onActivityResult(InvoiceFragment.java:62)
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$1.onStateChanged(ActivityResultRegistry.java:145)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:265)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3013)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:586)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3112)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3063)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:262)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:482)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7029)
    at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:7104)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7109)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1638) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your OnClick call the launch with null,  `mStartForResult.launch(null);`

and you can use `ActivityResultContracts.PickContact()`

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.PickContact(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            Cursor c =  getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + name);
                    c.close();
                }
        }
});
```

There are some examples in a youtube video called: ActivityResultContracts Android